# What is the difference between WaitForSecondsRealtime and a counter?

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui

I am making my own button using the Unity UI code, but now I got to the OnFinishSubmit () coroutine

```
private IEnumerator OnFinishSubmit()
{
    float fadeTime = base.colors.fadeDuration;
    float elapsedTime = 0f;
    while (elapsedTime < fadeTime)
    {
        elapsedTime += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    this.DoStateTransition(base.currentSelectionState, false);
    yield break;
}
```

But I want to use a different code to delay time

```
IEnumerator FinishSumbit()
{
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(colors.fadeDuration);

    DoStateTransition(currentSelectionState, false);
}
```

Will this also work?

Why didn't the Unity developers use WaitForSecondsRealtime?

Comment: "Will this also work?" — what do you observe when you try this code? "Why didn't the Unity developers use..." — you would have to ask them. We cannot tell you what a particular developer had in mind when writing specific code.

Comment: @DMGregory, Does it work the same?

Comment: You've already written the code. Try running it and find out. That will give you an answer more authoritative than hearsay from a stranger on the Internet.

Comment: The main difference I see is that in one case once the timer starts it is no longer changable.